# Docusign Envelope documents downloaded with size of 0 bytes

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I want to download the docusign envelope documents with the help of envelope id. Documents downloaded but unable to open because of filesize of 0 bytes.I tried a lot to fix the issue but can't figure out the problem.Can't anyone provide some reference?>
Note: Documents in envelope can be of any type like pdf,docx,etc.
Here is my code.

```
public function downloadDocument()
    {
        $envelopeId = "9d5fca0e-8e2d-408f-a4f4-2f8989e20898";
        // Step 1: Instantiate the API client and obtain an access token
        $apiClient = new ApiClient();
        $apiClient->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath(env('DS_AUTH_SERVER'));
        $accessToken = $this->getToken($apiClient);

        // Step 2: Set the API client's base path to the account's REST API URL
        $userInfo = $apiClient->getUserInfo($accessToken);
        $accountInfo = $userInfo[0]->getAccounts();
        $apiClient->getConfig()->setHost($accountInfo[0]->getBaseUri() . env('DS_ESIGN_URI_SUFFIX'));

        // Step 3: Call the DocuSign API to retrieve the list of documents in the envelope
        $envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
        $documents = $envelopeApi->listDocuments($accountInfo[0]->getAccountId(), $envelopeId);

        // Step 4: Send each document as a separate download response
        foreach ($documents->getEnvelopeDocuments() as $document) {
            $documentData = $envelopeApi->getDocument($accountInfo[0]->getAccountId(), $document->getDocumentId(), $envelopeId);
            // dd($documentData->getType());
            $response = response()->stream(function () use ($documentData) {
                echo $documentData;
            }, 200, ['Content-Type' => $document->getType(), 'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $document->getName() . '"']);
            $response->send();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be with the mime-type of the file and the way you try to get it sent back to the user.

See code in here - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Services/Examples/eSignature/EnvelopeGetDocService.php

Note that you have to check what is the file you're sending, it can be a ZIP, or PDF, and do this:

```
# Return the file information
if ($pdf_file) {
    $mimetype = 'application/pdf';
} elseif ($doc_item["type"] == 'zip') {
    $mimetype = 'application/zip';
} else {
    $mimetype = 'application/octet-stream';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "did not work"? did you get an error? what error?